# Which court does Xi'an belong to?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, kindred-of-the-east

Which court does Xi'an belong to? Is there a map of the Quincunx courts?

I know there is a map in Blood and Silk, but the Quincunx didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be the capital of the of Jade Court. (Xi'an was formerly called Chang'an; see page 157 rulebook). It had a very important role in *Blood and Silk* and *Wind from the East*.
If you're playing a modern-times chronicle, I'd place some really old Wu there that reminisce the times where they had much power.

Comment: Oh you're right. I saw Chang'an, but I didn't relate to Xi'an. Many thanks!